# Make Device's back button act like an Action Bar Up (back) button

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a settings activity and the user gets to choose a lot of different options to change the layout. Let's take the example of a light theme, when the user enables the light theme in the settings activity and goes back with the hardware's back button, the theme is still dark, but when he goes back with the action bar's back button the theme changes to light theme.

Thanks!!

Comment: is there any functionality on the actionbar back button for theme?

Comment: I'm guessing there isn't because I don't what do you mean haha

Comment: Did you add functionality onClick of actionbar back button ? if yes then call this method onBackPress.

Comment: I added it only to the action bar
`if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            onBackPressed();
}`

Comment: it should work can you past the code? if you are calling onBackPress on actionbar back button then it also work on hardware back button. check twice what you missed

Comment: AH now it works, stupid mistake on my part I forgot to add it to my settings activity, I pasted it in another's activity's code, thank you very much my friend!

Comment: But wait do you post your code in onOptionsItemSelected?

Comment: Still doesn't work :(

Comment: Can you post your code. otherwise I can not figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In settings activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
    super.onBackPressed();  // optional depending on your needs
}
```